# Evaluate Script events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

This https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/ says "Make a Timeline recording and look for suspiciously long Evaluate Script events.".

By `Evaluate Script` does it mean `eval` functions and how do you see these on the Timeline?

Comment: It means evaluation of any scripts by the browser when it parses the page: https://puu.sh/uxV70/2cc6dc5933.png

Answer (score -2):

When you make a [Performance recording](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/), the **Main** chart shows you all main-thread activity.

`Evaluate Script` means the events with that name that you see on the **Main** chart.

[image: evaluate script in main chart]

(Thanks wOxxOm for the image)

Source: I wrote that doc :)

Comment: `Evaluation Script` means `downloading`, `parsing` or `compiling` the JavaScript? And how do we know what each of its children are doing?

Comment: Yes, we see the label "Evaluate Script" in the Main chart. The entire question is what does that actually *mean*. What is the browser doing when it says "Evaluate Script"?

Comment: Well, I suppose now that I've heard the answer (from Jon Kuperman, https://frontendmasters.com/courses/chrome-dev-tools/profiling-the-main-thread/ ), it seems obvious: Evaluate Script is the browser parsing, compiling, and executing top-level statements in JS scripts.